# C++ How do you call a method for all members of a class?

Tags: c++, class

I have a class will many members and I want to
call a method for ALL membersof that class rather than
just an individual member

I could link all members of class via linked lists but is there a better way?

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows what you want to do.

Comment: what is the functionality of that method?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but linked lists are almost never the answer.

Comment: You need an array (or a vector), not a class.

Comment: maybe your members should be elements of a vector instead of members of a class?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do what you want is that if your elements(class memebres as you called them) are in an array so you can go through them all like this so 
i assume you want something similar to this

```
#include <algorithm>
#include<vector>
class A {};

void doSomething(A member) {}
int main() {
    std::vector<A> Amemebers;
    std::for_each(Amemebers.begin(), Amemebers.end(), doSomething);
}
```

Comment: I think the OP meant a class method, as in every object calling it individually, but this should work as well.

Comment: Your thoughts were very informative. I have been offshore hence the delay. For my application an array of class members was the answer as the member dont need to been dynamically allocated but a vector would be the answer if the members needed to dynamically alllocated

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not support reflection naively. This means that you cannot get a list of the members of a class. There may be external libraries and tools for this, but you cannot do that in standard C++.

So what you ask is not possible. What you need to do is to store the member variables in some kind of container, like `std::vector`.